# Approach to find duplicate - Kafka and queue

Tags: hashmap, queue

Question asked in interview ---Suppose there are two  kafaka topic or lets say queue - Q1 & Q2
Both are having some messages  suppose 10 messages each.

The condition here is if both the queue are having same messages exctaly same in both queue it's fine but if there is even one odd or non. matching message we need to error out or notify.

the approach i suggested for this problem.

1- Using hashset We can find.. we will add first queue message in add set and while adding other add method will notify us if  message  is not already there.

2- we can use the Hashmap and store it as key value form..while adding it i will check if the key -message is already  there.

but he was not satisfied he did not share the right answer or problem. with above approach.

Let me know if better solution exist and the problem with this approach

Answer (score 0):

He may have been aiming to get into a discussion about the difficulties of balancing in a real-time streaming situation. Let's say there is a continuous stream of messages going through the two topics how do you know if things are balanced?

There is no single answer, it depends on the situation but generally has to consider some kind of time window.

My guess is that the interviewer's dissatisfaction (if any) would be because he was looking to talk about options rather than going to one specific solution to a specific situation.

We can't know what he was thinking without asking (which I would always recommend) but when I'm interviewing I always look for candidates who can consider and discuss problems and trade-offs, not necessarily ones who have the 'right' solution.

Comment: Agreed to your point we need to take some window.. but lets say if take some window for real time scenario then what logic or strategy will you suggest to find the duplicate

Comment: Hi Nitin, that's not my point. My point is that these are not simple issues with simple answers and an interviewer will want to know that you can discuss trade-offs. I really don't believe they are looking for a black and white answer, and you may have greater success in interviews if you try not to just look for a single 'correct' answer when there may not be one.